# docker run -i -t image /bin/bash - source files first

Tags: bash, docker

This works:

```
# echo 1 and exit:
$ docker run -i -t image /bin/bash -c "echo 1"
1
# exit

# echo 1 and return shell in docker container:
$ docker run -i -t image /bin/bash -c "echo 1; /bin/bash"
1
root@4c064f2554de:/#
```

**Question**: How could I `source` a file into the shell? (this does not work)

```
$ docker run -i -t image /bin/bash -c "source <(curl -Ls git.io/apeepg) && /bin/bash"
# content from http://git.io/apeepg is sourced and shell is returned
root@4c064f2554de:/#
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I use `RUN source` command (which will run using /bin/bash) in a Dockerfile to install nvm for node.js

Here is an example.

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
...
...
RUN source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install 0.11.14
```

Comment: This only works during `docker build` and only for the same `RUN` instruction. The file won't be sourced when the resulting image is later started as a detached or interactive container.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted something similar, and expanding a bit on your idea, came up with the following:

```
docker run -ti --rm ubuntu \
  bash -c 'exec /bin/bash --rcfile /dev/fd/1001 \
                          1002<&0 \
                          <<<$(echo PS1=it_worked: ) \
                          1001<&0 \
                          0<&1002'
```

- `--rcfile /dev/fd/1001` will use that file descriptor's contents instead of .bashrc
- `1002<&0` saves stdin
- `<<<$(echo PS1=it_worked: )` puts `PS1=it_worked:` on stdin
- `1001<&0` moves this stdin to fd 1001, which we use as rcfile
- `0<&1002` restores the stdin that we saved initially

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.bashrc` in interactive containers:

```
RUN curl -O git.io/apeepg.sh && \
    echo 'source apeepg.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Then just run as usual with `docker run -it --rm some/image bash`.

Note that this will **only** work with interactive containers.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think you can do this, at least not right now. What you could do is modify your image, and add the file you want to source, like so:

```
FROM image
ADD my-file /my-file
RUN ["source", "/my-file", "&&", "/bin/bash"]
```

Comment: `source` is a built-in.  It doesn't exist as a `command`, so this just gives an error.